# IE Print CSS and spanning page breaks

Tags: css, internet-explorer, printing, css-float

I've been working on trying to fix an issue with print CSS and IE where things would disappear when printing in landscape mode.

It appears the issue is that the element I'm trying to print (a large DIV with content inside it) spans two pages when put into landscape mode. What is happening is when the element spans two pages, the first page is blank, and the second page is printing what would normally be left over from the first page.

I think it's related to contained floats:

wrapper div
   floated div1
   floated div2

If I set the two nested divs to float: none in the print CSS file, then IE will print them, albeit not in the layout we'd like.

Before I spend another hour on this, anyone know what, specifically, is the issue here and if there's a known workaround?

Answer (score 3):

The problem for me was that I was setting display:inline-block for the main container div. This along with declaring a width is a method to make a parent div extend to contain the floats inside.

I've removed display:inline-block and used clearfix instead. Problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with tables, but it may just be the nesting, but it is an IE bug.
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=257097
Still trying to work around the problem myself.

Comment: The MS support page reference says it applies to IE 5.5 & 6 but I'm getting the same issue in IE8. I removed the <thead> tags and it still has this behavior. If I set it to display 30% instead of "shrink to fit" it will display correctly, for what that's worth.